# Are these word orders all valid?

Tags: word-order

- Ich gab dem Mann dieses Auto.
- Ich gab dieses Auto dem Mann (or zum Mann ?).
- Dieses Auto gab ich dem Mann.
- Dem Mann gab ich dieses Auto.
- Dem Mann habe ich dieses Auto gegeben.
  Are these word orders all valid ? . Are there other word orders that I don't know ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all these sentences are correct. German word order mainly demands that the verb is in second position.

If we were to look at all possible permutations, there are more forms possible, however, they would be questions.

> Gab ich dieses Auto dem Mann?
>   Gab ich dem Mann dieses Auto?

Regarding whether you can say "Das Auto zum Mann geben"
No, the infinitive is "jemandem etwas geben"

As mentioned by c.p. in the comments, for the sake of completeness: If this sentence is in a Nebensatz, then it's also possible to say

> [...], ob ich dem Mann dieses Auto gab.
>   [...], ob ich dieses Auto dem Mann gab.

Comment: Can we replace 'dem Mann' with 'zum Mann' in all conditions and positions ?

Comment: No, you can't. I've updated my answer

Comment: what is 'jemandem' ?

Comment: can be questions or  relative clauses (e.g. *...ob ich dieses auto dem Mann gab*), if all permutations are required

Comment: jemandem is the Dativ form of jemand - "somebody"

Comment: 'jemandem etwas geben'  =   to give sth to someone / somebody?

Comment: Yes. But since English does not really have a dative case, they have to use "to", whereas in German you express this with the Dativ object.

Comment: Dem Mann = zu dem Mann = ' to the man '  ?

Comment: ' Zum Mann gab ich dieses Auto' is okay ?

Comment: No, as stated in my answer, it's not possible to say. Dem Mann does not mean "Zu dem Mann", there is a difference. You could ask a new question about the difference between "jemandem etwas bringen" and "etwas zu jemandem bringen".

Comment: This should be corrected in two aspects. One I mentioned before, and the second one is that your second sentence is wrong/not precise.

Comment: How is my second sentence wrong or not precise?